# How to fix "polyfit maybe poorly conditioned" in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do a polyfit on a set of data using numpy package.

The following is the code, it can run successfully. The fitted line seems to fit the data when the order reaches around 20(very high). However, at the end, it says "Polyfit may be poorly conditioned".

If I am not wrong, it is that when the degree gets higher, the fitting will be sensitive to the data, i.e. easily influenced by the data? How can I fix this?

```
def gen_data_9(length=5000):
x = 2.0 * (np.random.rand(length) - 0.5) * np.pi * 2.0
f = lambda x: np.exp(-x**2) * (-x) * 5 + x / 3
y = f(x) + np.random.randn(len(x)) * 0.5
return x, y, f

fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,3,figsize = (16,16))

for n in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
    
        order = 20*n+10*k+1
        z = np.polyfit(x,y,order)
        p = np.poly1d(z)

        ax[n,k].scatter(x,y,label = "Real data",s=1)
        ax[n,k].scatter(x,p(x),label = "Polynomial with order={}".format(order),
                    color='C1',s=1)
    ax[n,k].legend()

fig.show()
```

Comment: read the manual, do some examples by hand so you understand what's going on under the hood, and it should make more sense

Comment: If you want to suppress the warning:
`import warnings` `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', np.RankWarning)`

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR: In this case the warning means: **use a lower order!**

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

> Note that fitting polynomial coefficients is inherently badly conditioned when the degree of the polynomial is large or the interval of sample points is badly centered. The quality of the fit should always be checked in these cases. When polynomial fits are not satisfactory, splines may be a good alternative.

In other words, the warning tells you to double-check the results. If they seem fine don't worry. But are they fine? To answer that you should evaluate the resulting fit not only on the data points used for fitting (these often match rather well, especially when overfitting). Consider this:

```
xp = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10000) * 2 * np.pi

for n in range(3):
    for k in range(3):

        order = 20*n+10*k+1
        print(order)
        z = np.polyfit(x,y,order)
        p = np.poly1d(z)

        ax[n,k].scatter(x,y,label = "Real data",s=1)
        ax[n,k].plot(xp,p(xp),label = "Polynomial with order={}".format(order), color='C1')
        ax[n,k].legend()
```

Here we evaluate the polyfit on points spaced much more finely than the sample data. This is the result:

[image]

You can see that for orders 40 and above the results really shoot off. This coincides with the warnings I get.

Comment: [+1] for the most important question " **But are they fine?** " + One more point that can also help to answer this is to extend the range of **`x`**, say triple the range, that was self-contained in the data, to see, what each of a "synthetised" Model-Candidate proposes " ***in front*** " and " ***beyond*** " the observed data-sets points and there we check, if that indeed meets the reality we live in :o) **Anyway, a great lecture on critical thinking first,** thank you @kazemakase

Comment: Just a note that I encounter the same issue when using chebyshev fits. For instance, if I do np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebfit(x,y,deg) and deg is too large, it gives me the same error you have.

Answer (score 7):

You will get a better fit if you use the Polynomial class, although if you go past the ends of the data with a high order fit you will see the fast divergence shown above because you are extrapolating. To use the Polynomial class

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P
p = P.fit(x, y, order)
```

You can also experiment with more stable polynomial basis that will be better conditioned at high orders, say 100+, although that is hardly justified with noisy data like you are playing with.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev as T
p = T.fit(x, y, order)
```

You can get in bounds plotting points x, y from the fits like so:

```
plot(*p.linspace(500))
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! This helped me significantly resolve a lousy fit to a noisy curve (where I needed to "overfit" on purpose). Thanks a million!